# Partial Derivative of a Dot Product with Respect to one of its Vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Say we have a function

\begin{cases}
f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\\
f(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{u}^\top \mathbf{v}
\end{cases}

where $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Apparently taking the partial derivate of $f$ with respect to $\mathbf{v}$ yields $\mathbf{u}$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{u}$$

Why is that? This makes no sense to me. As $f$ returns real numbers, the rate of change in $f$ should be a real number, I would have assumed. Why is the rate of change a vector? Vectors are not even part of co-domain of $f$.

Also, what subject do I need to look into for this? I just got confronted with that isolated claim that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{u}$, [here](https://youtu.be/ERibwqs9p38?t=3074).

Comment: The differential of a real function of *several* variables *can't be* a real number.

Comment: Have you heard of Jacobian matrix ?

Comment: Oh! Jakobian commented himself!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial \textbf v}$ is a shorthand for $\left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial  v_1},...,\frac {\partial f}{\partial  v_n}\right)$, in other words it is the gradient of $f$. In this case, if you expand the dot product notation in terms of the coefficients, you obtain $\frac {\partial f}{\partial  v_i}=u_i$, so $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \textbf v} = \textbf u$.

In general, most rules for taking derivatives generalise well to taking derivatives with respect to vectors, as is done here, or even matrices. For a useful reference, I recommend [the matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), which has a list of identities. Proving a few might help you in your understanding.

Comment: Okay, so $f(v) = u \cdot v$, thus
$\nabla f =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \sum_i^n u_i v_i}{\partial v_1}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial \sum_i^n u_i v_i}{\partial v_n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
\vdots\\
u_n
\end{bmatrix}
= u
$